# time difference between transaction of user

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

```
Table: txn

customer_id | time_stamp 
-------------------------
1           | 00:01:03
1           | 00:02:04
2           | 00:03:05
2           | 00:04:06
```

Looking to query the time difference between each first transaction and next transaction of customer_id

Results:

### Customer ID | Time Diff

1           | 61

select customer_ID, ...
from txn

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Google BigQuery?  These are very different databases.

Comment: [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/)

Comment: Please specify, what DB is used, how data is inserted into the table, and how fetched?

Answer (score 1):

You want `lead()` . . . but date/time functions are notoriously database-specific.  In SQL Server:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second,
                time_stamp,
                lead(time_stamp) over (partition by customer_id order by time_stamp)
               ) as diff_seconds
from t;
```

In BigQuery:

```
select t.*,
       timestamp_diff(time_stamp,
                      lead(time_stamp) over (partition by customer_id order by time_stamp),
                       second
                     ) as diff_seconds
from t;
```